# How can I use a method in a different class?

Tags: java, class, methods, extend

I'm working on a project, and I need some help here.  I have an `AnimalWorld` that extends `World`, and an `Elephant` class that extends `Turtle`.  In my Elephant's `act()` method, I want to use a method (`public List getTurtleList()`), which is found only in `World` (and `AnimalWorld`).  I've tried addiding the line

```
public abstract List<Turtle> getTurtleList();
```

to AnimalWorld, and set Elephant to an abstract class, but I still get the error 'cannot find symbol - `getTurtleList()`
Any thoughts?  If you need more info, just let me know.  Also, Elephant does not extend AnimalWorld, as the elephants created are to be placed in the AnimalWorld.

```
public abstract class Elephant extends Turtle implements Animal{

    public Elephant(ModelDisplay world){

        super(world);
        this.penUp();
        this.setColor(Color.gray);
        this.setWidth(50);
        this.setHeight(50);
    }

    public void act(ModelDisplay myWorld){
        double smallestDist = 640.0;

        Mouse closestMouse = null;
        List<Turtle> animalList = myWorld.getTurtleList();

        for(Turtle curCritter: animalList){
            if(curCritter instanceof Mouse){
                int x=curCritter.getXPos();
                int y=curCritter.getYPos();
                double dist = this.getDistance(x,y);

                if(dist < 100 && dist<smallestDist){
                    closestMouse=curCritter;
                    smallestDist=dist;
                }
            }
        }

        if(closestMouse!=null){
            this.turn(closestMouse);
            this.forward(3*(int)smallestDist);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Elephant class that extends Turtle" isn't it strange

Comment: I would suggest you post the whole code with your errorcode. Is it homework ?

Comment: @Abu Sometimes Elephants can be Turtles, and in rare cases they can even fly.

Comment: First of all, african or asian elephant?

Comment: Guys we are diverting the point of discussion.

Comment: Elephant, or Turtle need to have a reference to a World object in order to be able to invoke the method you want.

Comment: okie, i agree with the guys that your inheritence relationship is weird, however does Turtle extend AnimalWorld ?? if so it shouldn't be hard. please post the code that you have so that you can get more help :)

Comment: `public abstract class Elephant extends Turtle implements Animal`. It gives me the impression that an Elephant is a type of Turtle and also and Animal, but a Turtle is not an Animal... :S Why Turtle is not implementig Animal?

Comment: Turtle was a class in this large file BookClasses, that my instructor gave me to use on various projects.  My animals needed an act method, so I created a separate class, Animal.  I didn't want to mess with Turtle, as it came to me already usable.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `World` class as:

```
public abstract class World{
    ...

    public abstract List<Turtle> getTurtleList();
}
```

will force you to implement a method called `getTurtleList()` in every class that inherits from `World`. If not, you will be forced to declare the subclass also as abstract. That's why you are forced to declare `Elephant` as an abstract class, because it doesn't implement all abstract methods from superclass.

Maybe you need to implement `getTurtleList()` in `AnimalWorld`, or in `Elephant`.

Comment: What do you mean, 'implement' in Elephant?  Elephant already implements Animal. I also can't declare World as abstract.  That doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your class diagram. Can you post it?